# Route mono to Left or Right instead of centered in FL Studio?

Tags: daw, homerecording, fl-studio, mono

This is my first post and hope I am on topic. In a DAW like Reaper when you record Mono mic on a track, it is by default centered. Same sound is then heard on both speakers.

However, I have been able to route L-Mono to speaker 1 and then same L-Mono input to  speaker 2 separately on 2 tracks in Reaper. In Routing option for a track, you can select 1 to 1 and 1 to 2 and accordingly input mono is routed to only Left  1 or Right 2 output speaker. So that  I can get a feel of two different pieces of music playing thru individual speakers.

Just for an example chords on left speaker in one track  and say some lead piece on right speaker on another track.

However I am trying out another DAW FL Studio 20 and not sure how to achieve the same in that DAW. Does anyone have any idea about the correct settings?

Hope I explained what I am trying to achieve. In case there’s existing QnA, kindly share the link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for how to pan audio.  Assuming you've already figured out how to get your mic into FL studio at all-

In the drop down menu where you select your input:

[image]

Select the appropriate mono (not stereo!) input for your mic.  You can do this on as many tracks as you like simultaneously.

Use the pan knob to pan this channel left or right (This may look slightly different depending on what mixer layout you have selected):

[image]

This pans the audio on that channel post-effects.  If you want to pan pre-effects, insert a panning plugin such as "fruity balance" into effects slot 1.

I'll note that there is a third panning option in the channel rack, which is only available on recorded audio or virtual instruments (not live audio) and is also pre-effects.  I only use it when I want several similar audio clips panned differently and passing through the same mixer channel.